# ReSharper 2017: Ignore File Layout Rules for Structs

Tags: resharper

I have a custom File Layout Type Pattern that formats my source files according to a specific set of preferences I defined. The formatting is applied automatically when I run code cleanup.

The problem I have is this: for structs that I use for P/Invoke the order of the members is important. How can I get ReSharper to ignore applying my File Layout Type Pattern for structs?

I think a previous version of ReSharper used to have this but in ReSharper 2017, I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In out-of-the-box File Layout, there is a special Pattern named "Non-recordable types", which does exactly what you want to reach:
[image]

It has "Struct" type inside and the main pattern won't touch any entity matched by this pattern.

[image]

It seems like your custom File Layout does not have such pattern.

However, you might add the following XML code to `<Patterns>` tag in Options to get it back (ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | File Layout | XAML button at the top)

```
  <TypePattern DisplayName="Non-reorderable types">
    <TypePattern.Match>
      <Or>
        <And>
          <Kind Is="Interface" />
          <Or>
            <HasAttribute Name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.InterfaceTypeAttribute" />
            <HasAttribute Name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComImport" />
          </Or>
        </And>
        <Kind Is="Struct" />
        <HasAttribute Name="JetBrains.Annotations.NoReorderAttribute" />
        <HasAttribute Name="JetBrains.Annotations.NoReorder" />
      </Or>
    </TypePattern.Match>
  </TypePattern>
```

Comment: I ended up having to add the XML code as you suggested because I was indeed missing that pattern. Thank you!